# Why my code is not launching the pinned shortcut of my App in Android 8+ (Oreo+)?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-webview, android-shortcut, pinned-shortcut

I'm trying to pin some dynamic shortcuts of my app, they are going to be created when the user creates a Custom time.

I have two version of the code, which I am launching the code from a **WebView** using a **JavaScriptInterface**, but none of them is working as expected since one of them is trying to open the Play Store and the second one says: *"the App doesn't exist"* when I created the shortcut from the App.

This one is launching the **Play Store**:

```
[Export]
[JavascriptInterface]
public void PinCustomTime(string time)
{
    var manager = context.GetSystemService(Context.ShortcutService) as ShortcutManager;

    if (manager.IsRequestPinShortcutSupported)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create the new intent
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            //Set the flag of the new task
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            //Get the apps from the Play Store
            intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("market://details?id=" + context.PackageName));
            //Set the custom time as a variable
            intent.PutExtra("customTime", time);
            //Set the info of the shortcut
            var info = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, $"tmTimer_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss")}")
                    .SetShortLabel("TM Timer")
                    .SetLongLabel("TM Timer")
                    .SetIcon(Icon.CreateWithResource(context, Resource.Drawable.iconInv))
                    .SetIntent(intent)
                    .Build();

            //Set values
            var successCallback = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, /* request code */ 0,
            intent, /* flags */ 0);
            //Creates the shortcut
            manager.RequestPinShortcut(info, successCallback.IntentSender);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This one is saying that the app doesn't exist:

```
[Export]
[JavascriptInterface]
public void PinCustomTime(string time)
{
    var manager = context.GetSystemService(Context.ShortcutService) as ShortcutManager;

    if (manager.IsRequestPinShortcutSupported)
    {
        try
        {
            //Set the info of the shortcut with the App to open
            var info = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, $"tmTimer_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss")}")
                    .SetShortLabel("TM Timer")
                    .SetLongLabel("TM Timer")
                    .SetIcon(Icon.CreateWithResource(context, Resource.Drawable.iconInv))
                    .SetIntent(new Intent(Intent.ActionView).SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(context.PackageName)))
                    .Build();

            //Create the new intent
            var intent = manager.CreateShortcutResultIntent(info);
            intent.PutExtra("customTime", time);

            //Set values
            var successCallback = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, /* request code */ 0,
            intent, /* flags */ 0);
            //Creates the shortcut
            manager.RequestPinShortcut(info, successCallback.IntentSender);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I tried a third code, but that one was trying to open any app that wasn't my own app. Does anyone have experienced something similar? Or know what am I missing?

I have followed multiple tutorials and examples like these ones:

- [Create pinned shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts#pinned)
- [Create app shortcut on home screen in Android Oreo(8.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478864/create-app-shortcut-on-home-screen-in-android-oreo8-0)
- [Android App Shortcuts New and Improved](https://medium.com/@calren24/android-app-shortcuts-new-and-improved-50139d4688f6)
- [Android App Shortcuts in Xamarin](https://trailheadtechnology.com/android-app-shortcuts-in-xamarin/)
- [Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Thanks for your support.

**P.S.:**

- All my tests have been done under Android Pie.
- I have built the code in Xamarin.Android in C#, but if you have an
  idea in Kotlin or Java, I can migrate it.

Comment: you could only create Pinned shortcuts on Android 8.0 (API level 26) and later

Comment: Hi @LeoZhu-MSFT, thanks for the comment. The original question was about Android Oreo+, I updated it. Could you test my code and let me know why it doesn't work in Android Pie? I tested in Android Oreo and Pie. Thanks.

Comment: ok，i will test it tomorrow and tell you result

Comment: Hi @LeoZhu-MSFT, thanks to atarasenko's answer, I was able to fix it, I posted my answer in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user clicks the shortcut, this intent will be launched:

```
new Intent(Intent.ActionView).SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(context.PackageName))
```

To launch a specific activity, replace it with (in java):

```
Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

Comment: I tried your second code before and it was trying to open X app like Google Maps, Chrome, etc. And my App was not in the list (this shouldn't even happen in my opinion). Any idea? Also, can you provide a fully functional example of a Pinned Shortcut with any of your Apps? Thanks.

Comment: Strange, it is working for me (on Emulator API 28). When the intent specifies the component name, it will launch only the specified Activity (MainActivity in this case), not Google Maps or so.

Comment: Maybe the only variant in my case, it's that I'm launching it from a webview, but I don't think it should influence or what do you think?

Comment: I added that section of the code to avoid any future misunderstanding.

Comment: I did a small changed based on your one and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The translation to C# is the following one:

```
[Export]
[JavascriptInterface]
public void PinCustomTime(string time)
{
    var manager = context.GetSystemService(Context.ShortcutService) as ShortcutManager;

    if (manager.IsRequestPinShortcutSupported)
    {
        //Create the new intent
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        //Set the flag of the new task
        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
        //Set the Time
        intent.PutExtra("customTime", time);
        //Set the info of the shortcut
        var info = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, $"tmTimer_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss")}")
                .SetShortLabel("TM Timer")
                .SetLongLabel("TM Timer")
                .SetIcon(Icon.CreateWithResource(context, Resource.Drawable.iconInv))
                .SetIntent(intent)
                .Build();

        //Set values
        var successCallback = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, /* request code */ 0,
        intent, /* flags */ 0);
        //Creates the shortcut
        manager.RequestPinShortcut(info, successCallback.IntentSender);
    }
}
```

I got some support from:

[How to get MainActivity for an Intent created in another class in Xamarin.Droid project?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/133427/how-to-get-mainactivity-for-an-intent-created-in-another-class-in-xamarin-droid-project)